# What is determining the items that make the difference between two arrays called?

Tags: algorithm

I want to find which elements of two arrays make the two arrays different.

For example, if I start off with

```
known_unacceptable_array = [bad, bad, good, good, good, bad, good]
known_acceptable_array = []
```

and an array is only unacceptable if there's three `bad`s (but I don't know that at the time), but I'm able to evaluate whether an array is acceptable or unacceptable, I would like to find the smallest array that makes the array unacceptable

```
possibly_minimal_unacceptable = [bad, bad, bad]
maximal_acceptable = [bad, bad] # Third bad required to make the array unacceptable
```

What is this problem called, and what algorithms are there for this?

**Edit:** The elements can't be changed in order, and adding an element can only either change the list from being acceptable to unacceptable or have no effect - it can't change it from being unacceptable to acceptable.

**Background:** I've randomly generated thousands of instructions that make a ruby interpreter crash, and I want to isolate the specific instructions that cause it to crash, and at the time I thought that multiple bad instructions were required to make it crash. A very naive attempt to determine what the bad instructions is at [this link](https://github.com/agrimm/small_eigen_collider/blob/master/lib/small_eigen_collider/array_chopper.rb)

Comment: "A predicate". I don't understand the intent from the question: from the simple cases you are just counting the filtered (on "bad") sequence -- if it's over 2, it's bad. A manual loop process and counter could eager-quit a tad sooner, but I really don't think I understand the intent of the question.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. I don't see how to relate your example to the question in the title. "an array is only bad if there's three `bad`s" — Is this (sort of) information fixed and given to you, or is (more likely) what you have an oracle/blackbox that *given* an array tells you whether it's "good" or "bad"? If the latter, what properties does this blackbox function have? Do you want a minimum-in-size array at the end, or just minimal under inclusion (i.e. no subset is also "bad")?

Comment: @pst: What do you mean by `"A predicate"`?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Was this comment written before or after the edit about adding elements can only make no effect or change from non-bad to bad?

Comment: @Andrew: No, after. I still don't understand anything about your question. Please state it more clearly, or at least answer the questions I asked.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I was assuming that I was facing a black box, but one where removing an element couldn't change it from being good to being bad.

Answer (score 0):

> What is determining the elements that make the difference
>   between two arrays called?

Differencing is often called
*subtraction.*

> I want to determine which elements of two arrays make the
>   two arrays different.

Again, that's *subtraction*(at least
some form of it):
     Given A ={ x , y , z } B = { x , y a },
     A - B = { z , -a }

or "only A has z and only B has a", or "z and a" make them
different.

> For example, if I start off with

```
known_bad = [bad, bad, good, good, good, bad, good] >
known_good = []
```

Why start with a full array and an empty one? Isn't this an
extreme case, or are these "two arrays" not two of which you
are trying to determine the "difference."

> possibly_minimal_bad = [bad, bad, bad]
>   maximal_good = [bad, bad] # Third bad required to make the list bad

Is this just a set of rules?  Or is this the result of
finding the difference between the two arrays of the previous
(known_good,bad) set?

> What is this problem called, and what algorithms are there
>   for this?

1. If it isn't called "difference" or "subtraction" then why
   introduce it that way?
2. Is  the problem: a. going from
   the first two arrays (known_xx) to the second two (min,max);
   or is it: b. classifying finite sequences of the words "good"
   and "bad."
   a) I can't see a relation between the first two
   arrays and the second two.  How did you get from the first two
   to the second?
   b) Classifying a sequence of words could be
   "parsing a language", or decoding a message, recognizing a
   pattern, etc.

**Is it "Pattern Recognition"?**

It appears that you are looking for a pattern in test input(or test point) data and it's relationship to product failure,
 and want to represent the relationship in some codical 
form for further analysis.  Or searching for a *correlation* between certain test points and product failure. That makes this question rather
interesting.  However, the presentation of the question
is quite confusing. Maybe  those groups of
equations  could be explained a little more, clarifying if they are related,and if so, then: In what way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand the question. If my answer is unsatisfactory, please rephrase your question to be more clear. I'll base my answer on this.

> I want to determine which elements of two arrays make the two arrays different.

This is a combination of the three set operations union, intersection and difference. Different combinations can achieve the same result.

- *Complement* is the the subset of A which is not in B.
- *Intersection* is the set of elements which is both in A and B, but not just A *or* B.
- *Union* is the subset which is either in A or B (no duplicates).

It sounds like you want the union of both complements, which is:

```
A\B ∪ B\A
```

Or the complement between the intersection and the union:

```
A∩B \ A∪B
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(Boolean) for more information.